# Computing $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,nK)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to understand why $\dim H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,nK)=0$ for $n\geq 1$ and $K=-2\infty$, a canonical divisor on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

By Riemann-Roch, we have that $h^0(nK)=h^0(K-nK)+\deg(nK)+1$, which isn't obviously helpful since $\deg(K-nK)=-2+2n$ so we can't conclude that $H^0(K-nK)=0$.

So instead, looking directly at $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,nK)$, we have $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,nK)=\{f\in K(\mathbb{P}^1)\mid \operatorname{div}(f)\geq 2n\infty\}$. But I'm not sure why this should just be the constant functions. For instance, if we let $K(\mathbb{P}^1)=K(t)$, then $1/t^{2n}$ is a non-constant function in this space. So am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you want to use Riemann-Roch? This is much easier from the knowledge that $H^0(\Bbb P^r_R,\mathcal{O}(n))\cong R[x_0,\cdots,x_r]_{n}$, which when $n<0$ is zero. This is a very standard computation available in any algebraic geometry book dealing with sheaf cohomology.

Comment: @KReiser That's certainly a simpler way of looking at it. But what is wrong with my computation in the last paragraph?

Comment: You used the wrong definition - you want $\{f\in K(\Bbb P^1) \mid (f) + D \geq 0\}$. So you need $f$ to be regular away from $\infty$ and have a zero of order at least $2n$ at $\infty$. So $f$ is a regular function which is zero at one point, hence zero (as all globally regular functions are constant).